# How to create a sub-Table by multiple conditions?

Tags: excel

I've a table `Tabelle2` formatted as a Table in Excel. One column `KW` contains numbers and missing values:

```
 KW=[1,1,5,6,7,#NV,#NV]
```

and the other column contains text. I want a sub table with only the rows in `KW` `>= max(KW)-1` and without `#NV`.

How to do it in Excel?

For better understanding in R I would just do:

```
SubTable=Tabelle2[Tabelle2$KW >= (max(Tabelle2$KW)-1) && Tabelle2$KW != "#NV";]
```

Comment: This question is not very clear, but the `Advanced Filter` will allow you to create dynamic criteria and create a new table based on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Advanced Filter as suggested by @Byron, with layout as shown and the criteria in C2 of:

```
  =AND(A5>=MAX(A$5:A$11)-1,A5<>"#NV")
```

[image: SO30457909 example]

The output table is as highlighted in C13:D15.